# Render a scene twice but once it renders with an extra object

Tags: rendering, scene, render-layers, compositing-nodes

Hi i have a scene with a kitchen and i am using the sky texture and a large volume to create godrays, except to make the scene less noisy i am rendering it twice with two identical scenes but one has this volumetric effect and i am using the compositer to blend the two renders, but i am trying to reduce file size and want to find a way to get rid of the duplicate scene and simply render twice but once have this volume, i believe it is possible as the vfx setup can do this but i have no idea how this works, any help would be perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i figured it out, in blender 2.79 they had something called render layers, in 2.8, and 2.9 they use view layers, to do this you will see ticks in the outliner, and unticking them will make them not be rendered, and in the top right there is a section called view layers, if you duplicate them with the same settings you can tick or untick each one and then composite them together